# Word for this situation (dark environment)

Tags: single-word-requests

I really like thinking in abstract and recently had the chance to visit a place again after a long time which is just not the same anymore. The environment and people had kinda become like *'this'* from the Powerpuff Girls episode.

[image]

[image]

People had deteriorated mainly because of age.

So I just need a word for this whole situation. 
The closest word I can think about is apocalyptic. But I think, of course, it's a bit extreme. Since there hasn't been any major event. It's just that everything has lost its energy naturally due to not good planning, for the worst.
Please suggest.

Comment: Depending on what exactly the show is depicting, perhaps *aged* or *decrepit* or *decaying* or *zombie* or maybe *zombie-like*.

Comment: For single-word requests, I think you're supposed to write a sentence in which you want to use the word and a put a blank (______) where you want the requested word to go.

Comment: Unlike a spoonful of sugar, *kinda* doesn't always go down well when you're asking questions!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it has become that way because of age, perhaps ***decrepit*** will work.

> #### Decrepit
>
> *adjective*
>
> 1. Worn out or ruined because of age or neglect.
> 2. Wasted and weakened by or as if by the infirmities of old age.

([M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/decrepit))

Answer (score 3):

***Dilapidated*** -- [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dilapidated)

> decayed, deteriorated, or fallen into partial ruin especially through neglect or misuse

Answer (score 3):

The place has **gone to seed**. To *[go to seed](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/go_to_seed)* means, literally and metaphorically, that the period of flowering and fructification has passed.

Answer (score 1):

Although it might imply a “moral corruption” too strongly for your tastes, I think *Merriam-Webster*’s ...

> “verb (past participle/adjective)-1:to pass from a higher to a lower
>   type or condition” and
>
> “noun-2:  a lowering … to an enfeebled and worsened kind or state”

... meanings for “[degenerate{d}](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/degenerated)” and “[degeneration](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/degeneration)”, respectively, could work well (in a pinch) for both the environment/town and its residents:

“the town’s degeneration”//“the degeneration of the town”//“the degenerated town”

“the degeneration of the villagers//”their degeneration”//“the degenerated [condition/look of the] villagers”